# "Wine is a mocker, strong drinkg is raging" - what does the latter part mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

In a story from C.A. Smith, there is a following sentence in the very beginning:

> I thank you, friend, but I am no drinker of wine, not even if it be
> the rarest Canary or the oldest Amontillado. Wine is a mocker, strong
> drink is raging ...

What does the "strong drink is raging" part mean? The literary translation does not make sense to me, or could anyone suggest another way of saying that so it will be more clear to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling this phrase shows it is a quote from the Bible.  [Proverbs 20:1](https://biblehub.com/proverbs/20.htm) King James Version.  The author (Solomon?) tells us that wine makes us foolish, and 'strong drink' (or perhaps beer, in some translations) makes us angry and want to fight.  So a King should avoid both (because when Kings get angry, people die)

It's always worth putting an odd phrase into a search engine. Sometimes it turns out to be a quote or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is it, since there is a reference to the King Solomon later in the text.